# maximal sum of matrix values and dividers algorithm

Tags: algorithm, matrix

I just had a test in algorithms (NOT HOMEWORK) and i have a question i wasn't sure about:

Let T be a table of size 2n (2 rows and n columns). each cell has a non-negative value and each divider (line that divides between cells) has a non-positive value.

The goal is to choose cells in T so that this is as maximal as possible:
the sum of the values of the cells that we picked + the sum of the values of the dividers between every 2 neighbor cells we picked.

I need to find an algorithm that achieves this goal in linear time (or as best as i can if not linear).

I didn't really have an idea where to start and i'd love to get some ideas.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Here's a hint: try to use dynamic programming.

Comment: @arghbleargh i thought about that but dynamic programming is always  is squared time (or logarithmic time at best). i'm not sure it's possible to use dynamic programming in linear time.